# Cron Job Failure on GAE using java with automatic scaling

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, objectify

I am trying to use cron job for executing some work once a day. I am using automatic scaling. Using cron job i am sending emails once a day. I have 2 conditions:

1. Whenever i set time once a day for example `every day 18:00` then cron job run successfully but its only executing 3, 4 lines of CronJob implementation class.
   In logger I am getting only 4 lines are executing like this:-

   [image]
2. whenever i set time as `every 2 minutes` or `every 5 minutes` then cron job run successfully and cron job implementation class executed successfully means its send email successfully.

Why is the first condition not sending email?

Is there may be app is at that time idle and that's why it's not executing?

Any help?
 Cron.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <cron>
    <url>/slick_erp/cronCustomerService</url>
    <description>Implemented for due services of customer.</description>
    <schedule>every day 11:30</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Web.xml:-

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CustomerServiceCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.CustomerServiceCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CustomerServiceCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronCustomerService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My cronjob implementation class :-

```
public class CustomerServiceCronJobImpl extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6268357776825855510L;


    private SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    private SimpleDateFormat fmt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");




     Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NameOfYourLogger");

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

                servicecontactlist();

        }



        private void servicecontactlist() {
            fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
            fmt1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
            Email cronEmail = new Email();  

                    Date today=DateUtility.getDateWithTimeZone("IST", new Date());

                    /**
                     *   Adding 1 day extra to date
                     */

                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date Before Adding One Day"+today);
                    DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(today);
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);

                    Date dateForFilter=null;

                    try {
                        dateForFilter=dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
                        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
                        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
                        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,999);
                        dateForFilter=cal.getTime();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date After Adding One Date"+dateForFilter);

                    /*************************************End*********************************/

         try{

             logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In service ContactList"); 
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date After Adding One Date=="+dateForFilter);

            logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 1 ");
        /********************************Adding status in the list ***********************/
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 2 ");

             ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
             obj.add("Scheduled");
             obj.add("Pending");
             obj.add("Rescheduled");

            logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 3 ");

        /******************************Converting todayDate to String format*****************/
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 4 ");

             Date todaysDate = new Date();
             SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 5 ");

             String todayDateString = df.format(todaysDate);

                logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 6 ");

             System.out.println("String in dd/MM/yyyy format is: " + todayDateString);
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 7 ");


       /********************************Adding Companies in the list ***********************/
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 8 ");

        List<Company> compEntity = ofy().load().type(Company.class).list();

        logger.log(Level.SEVERE," 9 ");

            if(compEntity.size()>0){

                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"If compEntity size > 0");
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Size of compEntity"+compEntity.size());


                for(int i=0;i<compEntity.size();i++){

                    Company c=compEntity.get(i);
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In the for loop");
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Company Name="+c);
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"The value of i is:" +i);
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date After Adding One Date"+dateForFilter);
 /********************************Checking prosname & prosconfig for each company ***********************/
                    ProcessName prosName = ofy().load().type(ProcessName.class).filter("processName","CronJob").filter("status",true).filter("companyId", compEntity.get(i).getCompanyId()).first().now();
                    ProcessConfiguration prosconfig = ofy().load().type(ProcessConfiguration.class).filter("processList.processName", "CronJob").filter("processList.processType", "ServiceDailyMail").filter("processList.status",true).filter("companyId", compEntity.get(i).getCompanyId()).first().now();                   
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"after 3 filters for ProcessConfigurations");
                    System.out.println("after 3 filters for ProcessConfigurations");

                    if(prosName!=null){
                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In the prossName");
                    if(prosconfig!=null){

                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In the ProsConfifg !=null ");


            /********************************Reading services from Service entity  ***********************/

                        List<Service> serEntity = ofy().load().type(Service.class).filter("companyId",compEntity.get(i).getCompanyId()).filter("serviceDate <=",dateForFilter).filter("status IN",obj).list();

                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Today date Is:"+dateForFilter);    

                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"service entity size:"+serEntity.size());   


                        // email id is added to emailList
                        ArrayList<String> toEmailList=new ArrayList<String>();
                        toEmailList.add(compEntity.get(i).getPocEmail());

                         String mailTitl = "Services Due As On Date";

                        if(serEntity.size()>0){


                        ArrayList<String> tbl_header = new ArrayList<String>();
                        tbl_header.add("Branch");
                        tbl_header.add("Customer Id");
                        tbl_header.add("Customer Name");
                        tbl_header.add("Customer Contact No");
                        tbl_header.add("Crontact Id");
                        tbl_header.add("Service Id");
                        tbl_header.add("Service Date");
                        tbl_header.add("Service Engineer");
                        tbl_header.add("Product Name");
                        tbl_header.add("Status");
                        tbl_header.add("Ageing");

        /********************************Sorting table with Branch & Service Date ***********************/


                        Comparator<Service> serviceDateComparator2 = new Comparator<Service>() {
                            public int compare(Service s1, Service s2) {

                            Date date1 = s1.getServiceDate();
                            Date date2 = s2.getServiceDate();

                            //ascending order
                            return date1.compareTo(date2);
                            }
                            };
                            Collections.sort(serEntity, serviceDateComparator2);

                            Comparator<Service> serviceDateComparator = new Comparator<Service>() {
                                public int compare(Service s1, Service s2) {

                                String branch1 = s1.getBranch();
                                String branch2 = s2.getBranch();

                                //ascending order
                                return branch1.compareTo(branch2);
                                }

                                };
                                Collections.sort(serEntity, serviceDateComparator);

    /********************************Getting serviceEntity data and adding in the tbl1 List ***********************/

                        ArrayList<String> tbl1=new ArrayList<String>();

                        for(int j=0;j<serEntity.size();j++){
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getBranch()+"");
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getPersonInfo().getCount()+"");
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getPersonInfo().getFullName()+"");
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getPersonInfo().getCellNumber()+"");
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getContractCount()+"");
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getCount()+"");
                            tbl1.add(fmt.format(serEntity.get(j).getServiceDate()) +"");

                            /**************** for getting ageing for each service******/
                        String StringServiceDate = fmt1.format(serEntity.get(j).getServiceDate());

//                          String StringServiceDate = df.format(serviceDate);  

                                Date d1 = null;
                                Date d2 = null;

                                d1 = df.parse(StringServiceDate);
                                d2 = df.parse(todayDateString);
                                long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
                                long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                                System.out.println("Ageing:"+diffDays);
                                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Ageing:"+diffDays);

                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getEmployee()+""); 
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getProduct().getProductName()+"");
                            tbl1.add(serEntity.get(j).getStatus()+"");
                            tbl1.add(diffDays +"");
                        }           

                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In the ProsConfig !=null   3 ");

             /********************************Calling cronsendEmail Method ***********************/

//                      Email e=new Email();                    
                        try {   

                                System.out.println("Before send mail method");
                                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Before send method call to send mail  ");                      
                                cronEmail.cronSendEmail(toEmailList, "Services Due As On Date"+" "+ todayDateString, mailTitl +"  "+ todayDateString, c, tbl_header, tbl1, null, null, null, null);
                                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"After send mail method ");     
                                        //+"  "+
                        } catch (IOException e1) {

                            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In the catch block ");
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    }
                    else{                   // else block for if(serviceEntity.size()>0){       

                        System.out.println("Sorry no services found for this company");
                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Sorry no services found for this company");
//                      
                        mailTitl = "No Services Found Due";

                        cronEmail.cronSendEmail(toEmailList, "Services Due As On Date"+" "+ todayDateString, mailTitl , c, null, null, null, null, null, null);

                    }


                    }
                    else{                   //else block for prosconfig
                            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"ProcessConfiguration is null");
                            System.out.println("ProcessConfiguration is null");
                    }

                    }else{        //else block for pross!=null
                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Cron job status is Inactive");
                        System.out.println("Cron job status is Inactive");
                    }


                }   //end of for loop

            }
            else{           //else block for if(compEntity.size()>0)

                logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"No Company found from cron job completed");    
                System.out.println("No Company found from cron job completed");
            }


        }catch(Exception e2){

            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: Since a short interval is working... Can you check whether your warmup requests and the execution of your cron task take longer thant 60 seconds?

Comment: Thank you for valuable response I am new on GAE what is warmup request ? And with cron job is there limitation on 60 seconds?

Comment: The limit for tasks should be 10 minutes - so forget that i mentioned the 60 seconds. Anyways it could very well be that your tasks runs too long. Do you mind posting the code of your cron task?

Comment: Thank you but if problem with my code then it also not be execute at every 5 minutes but it work with that so.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. The code as well as you web.xml and your cron.xml is of relevance.

Comment: yes exactly i added cron.xml and web.xml in my Question check it plz

Comment: I added my cronjob implementation class also plz check it i am waiting for your response

Comment: Your configuration looks alright. Your code, well, there's just too many unknowns. It does explain the error messages in the app engine logs (since you log almost everything as severe). If i were you i'd throw out all of the code and start with very little code. Then work up to the full functionality step by step and see when it breaks.

Comment: Thank you konqi for your respone. I edit my screen shot please check it i got information like This request caused a new process to be started for your application, so please check my Screen Shot image

Comment: The same code i was executed yesterday at night

Comment: The same code i was executed yesterday at night   just simply added more logs like  1 2 3 then i got the code  List<Company> compEntity = ofy().load().type(Company.class).list(); whenever this line executing then it's throwing information like "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, ....."  for details please check my screen shot and my code i edited.

Comment: " This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."