# Cron job run on time but failure to execute ofy().load().type().... query any configure i require in appengine.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, objectify

I working on project using java on GAE. I used cron job for some remainders. I set time for cron job once a day. GAE run cron job at time but my cron job Implementation class execute on stating 4 5 lines only after 5 lines there is ofy code hat is not executed why? bellow is my code

My appengine-web.xml:-

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">    
<application>evadev014</application>
version>9</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<instance-class>F4_1G</instance-class>

<!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
<static-files>
<include path="**" />
 <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
<include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />
<include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
<exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
</static-files>

<!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
<system-properties>
<property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>
```

My Cron.xml :-

```
<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronPhysicalInventoryCronJob</url>
<description>Implemented for due stock. </description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronCustomerService</url>
<description>Implemented for due services of customer.</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronContractRenewal</url>
<description>Implemented for due contract renewal. </description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronCustomerARPayment</url>
<description>Implemented for due payments of customer. Accounts Receivable.</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronLead</url>
<description>Implemented for due leads of customer.</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronDeliveryNote</url>
<description>Implemented for pending delivery notes of customer.</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronCustomerAPPayment</url>
<description>Implemented for due payments of customer. Accounts Payable.</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronCustomerAPInvoice</url>
<description>Implemented for due invoices of customer. Accounts Payable</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronCustomerARInvoice</url>
<description>Implemented for due invoices of customer. Accounts Receivable</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronSalesQuotation</url>
<description>Implemented for due sales quotations of customers.</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronServiceQuotation</url>
<description>Implemented for due service quotation of customers.</description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronGoodsReceiptNote</url>
<description>Implemented for due GRNs. </description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>

<cron>
<url>/slick_erp/cronApproval</url>
<description>Implemented for due approvals. </description>
<schedule>every day 04:00</schedule>
</cron>
```

My web.xml :-

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>CustomerServiceCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.CustomerServiceCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CustomerServiceCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronCustomerService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>      

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DeliveryNoteCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.DeliveryNoteCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DeliveryNoteCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronDeliveryNote</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CustomerPaymentAPCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.CustomerPaymentAPCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CustomerPaymentAPCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronCustomerAPPayment</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CustomerPaymentARCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.CustomerPaymentARCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CustomerPaymentARCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronCustomerARPayment</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InvoiceAPCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.InvoiceAPCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InvoiceAPCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronCustomerAPInvoice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InvoiceARCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.InvoiceARCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InvoiceARCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronCustomerARInvoice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SalesQuotationCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.SalesQuotationCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SalesQuotationCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronSalesQuotation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServiceQuotationCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ServiceQuotationCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServiceQuotationCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronServiceQuotation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GoodsRecievedNoteCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.GoodsReceiptNoteCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GoodsRecievedNoteCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronGoodsReceiptNote</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LeadCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.LeadCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LeadCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronLead</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ContractRenewalCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ContractRenewalCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ContractRenewalCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronContractRenewal</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PhysicalInventoryCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.PhysicalInventoryCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PhysicalInventoryCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronPhysicalInventoryCronJob</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ApprovalCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.slicktechnologies.server.cronjobimpl.ApprovalCronJobImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ApprovalCronJobImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slick_erp/cronApproval</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My logger i geting like this :- 
[image]

Before OFY code its executing when ofy().load.... lines not executing why?

This is one of my cron job code:-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.simplesoftwares.client.library.ReturnFromServer;
import com.simplesoftwares.client.library.libservice.GenricService;
import com.simplesoftwares.client.library.libservice.GenricServiceAsync;
import com.slicktechnologies.client.utility.AppConstants;
import com.slicktechnologies.server.Email;
import com.slicktechnologies.server.utility.DateUtility;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.businessprocesslayer.Customer;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.businessunitlayer.Company;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.helperlayer.SmsConfiguration;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.helperlayer.SmsTemplate;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.numbergenerator.ProcessName;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.processconfiguration.ProcessConfiguration;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.salesprocess.CustomerPayment;
import com.slicktechnologies.shared.common.smshistorydetails.SmsHistory;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.SmsFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

public class CustomerPaymentARCronJobImpl extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1352789385430511259L;


    private SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    private SimpleDateFormat fmtPaymentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NameOfYourLogger");



        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

                custPaymentARlist();
        }

        private void custPaymentARlist() {





            Email cronEmail = new Email();

            Date today=DateUtility.getDateWithTimeZone("IST", new Date());
            fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
            fmtPaymentDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));;
            /**
             *   Adding 1 day extra to date
             */

            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date Before Adding "+today);
            DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(today);
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);

            Date dateForFilter=null;

            try {
                dateForFilter=dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,999);
                dateForFilter=cal.getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date After setting the Time"+dateForFilter);

            /************************************* End *********************************/


     try{

         logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In Payment AR List"); 
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date After Adding One Date"+dateForFilter);


    /********************************Adding status in the list ***********************/

         ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
         obj.add("Created");
         obj.add("Requested");



    /******************************Converting todayDate to String format*****************/

         Date todaysDate = new Date();
         SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
         String todayDateString = df.format(todaysDate);
         System.out.println("String in dd/MM/yyyy format is: " + todayDateString);


 /********************************Adding Companies in the list ***********************/

    List<Company> compEntity = ofy().load().type(Company.class).list();
    if(compEntity.size()>0){

        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"If compEntity size > 0");
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Size of compEntity"+compEntity.size());


        for(int i=0;i<compEntity.size();i++){

            Company c=compEntity.get(i);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"In the for loop");
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Company Name="+c);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"The value of i is:" +i);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Date After Adding One Date"+dateForFilter);
```

I am not getting this logger and below this line logger :-  logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Size of compEntity"+compEntity.size()); as i showed in my program

any help?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron Job Failure on GAE using java with automatic scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773741/cron-job-failure-on-gae-using-java-with-automatic-scaling)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: not i am explaind here with appengine.xml if any configuration need

Comment: I read both questions very carefully and i'm fairly certain that the core issue is the same. Asking the same thing twice in different ways won't help much. If you want Stackoverflow users to help you should create a **minimal complete verifiable example** (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm convinced that if you create such an example you will also find the cause of the issue. Mostly because in my humble opinion the cause is, frankly put, the mess you call code.