# Cron Job success on time but not executing Ofy() query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I am using cron job in my project. I am executing cron job once a day at night at that time my app has no activity no user login so that time my app is on idle. So that time My cron job triggered on time but it is not executing :-

```
List<Branch> branchentity= ofy().load().type(Branch.class).list();
```

cron job executing some code before above line but when it comes to above line then its not executing why? any other solutions?  any other solutions to get datastore entuty data in the list without using of ofy?

Any help

thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a minimal complete verifiable example (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I myself have lots of cron jobs that perform datastore queries with Objectify and they all work, so the problem cannot be diagnosed with only a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks but your cron job run when your app has no activity? and once day?

Comment: yes. I have cron jobs set up in multiple projects that run at 2 am local time to clean up the database when there is no other load on the application.

Comment: Thanks but why its not working with me apps any solution

Comment: I'm not doubting that there's a problem. I'm just saying that it's impossible to diagnose from the single line of code you provide. Create an example as described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and you'll get all the help you need. Similar Issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951806/cron-job-run-on-time-but-failure-to-execute-ofy-load-type-query-any-co, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773741/cron-job-failure-on-gae-using-java-with-automatic-scaling

Comment: Thanks but one more thing if i just login to my app  sample.appspot.com and log out before 10 mins of cron job triggered then cron job execute this line ofy() and giving output

Comment: Excellent! So this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773741/ where i requested an example to work with as well.